# reset tr input fields with jquery button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a table with input fields for class teachers to save their students data in a sheet so  principal can check it in a sheet, in this table every tr have update and reset button, so teacher can save his text in fields or reset them, 
My html table structure is this

```js
<script>
var input = $( "input:reset" ).css({
  background: "yellow",
  border: "3px red solid"
});
$( "div" )
  .text( "For this type jQuery found " + input.length + "." )
  .css( "color", "red" );
 
// Prevent form submission
$( "form" ).submit(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
});
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tr>
      <td>211</td>
      <td><textarea placeholder="Title" width="500"></textarea></td>
      <td><textarea placeholder="First name"></textarea></td>
      <td><textarea placeholder="Last name"></textarea></td>
      <td><textarea placeholder="speciality"></textarea></td>
      <td><input type="button" class="button" value="update"></td>
      <td><input type="reset" class="button" value="Reset"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
      <td>211</td>
      <td><textarea placeholder="Title" width="500"></textarea></td>
      <td><textarea placeholder="First name"></textarea></td>
      <td><textarea placeholder="Last name"></textarea></td>
      <td><textarea placeholder="speciality"></textarea></td>
      <td><input type="button" class="button" value="update"></td>
      <td><input type="reset" class="button" value="Reset"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
      <td>211</td>
      <td><textarea placeholder="Title" width="500"></textarea></td>
      <td><textarea placeholder="First name"></textarea></td>
      <td><textarea placeholder="Last name"></textarea></td>
      <td><textarea placeholder="speciality"></textarea></td>
      <td><input type="button" class="button" value="update"></td>
      <td><input type="reset" class="button" value="Reset"></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
      <td>211</td>
      <td><textarea placeholder="Title" width="500"></textarea></td>
      <td><textarea placeholder="First name"></textarea></td>
      <td><textarea placeholder="Last name"></textarea></td>
      <td><textarea placeholder="speciality"></textarea></td>
      <td><input type="button" class="button" value="update"></td>
      <td><input type="reset" class="button" value="Reset"></td>
 </tr>
```

this is my code, one time it worked for me but if I reset on tr it reset all tr fields from one to last, now its not working, and I want to apply reset function for one tr,
Mean
every tr have reset button, I just want If I click a reset button it reset only its own tr's input fields do not effect other tr.

Comment: How you are binding onclick event in reset ?

Comment: @MahbuburRahman by selecting input type reset.

Comment: I am not expert in it, can you help me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to find just the textarea elements that you want cleared, and change their values. Something like this should work:

```
$('input[type="reset"]').on('click', function(e) {
  var $tr = $(e.target).closest('tr'),
      $textAreas = $tr.find('textarea');

  $textAreas.val('');
  return false;
});
```

Comment: I also need to make update button working, reset button is fine, can you please help me to make update button working?

Comment: my limit to post question is finishd, that's why I asked you,